# Snowflake JSON : return all errors with csv as File_Format type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get JSON loading errors structured like CSV Validation_Mode.
The query on json section of [this page](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#supported-file-formats) is returning the first error, which looks good to me.

Query:

```
COPY INTO "PUBLIC"."MyTable"("Col1", "Col2")
FROM 
(
    SELECT parse_json($1):Col1, parse_json($1):Col2
    FROM @my_json_stage/MyTable.json
)
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = csv FIELD_DELIMITER = none RECORD_DELIMITER = '\\n') 
FORCE=TRUE 
ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE';
```

I am wondering if there is a convenient way to display more errors using this method or not.

Comment: This is the recommended way to get errors for JSON files.  I'll let you know if I think of anything else, but it might be a feature request to improve it further.